# match array with text in DIV

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of names, which i need to see if they match names in a DIV:

```
var topicName = []; 
$.each(top3, function(i, item) {
    if (item.featured === false) {
        topicName.push(item.username);
    }    
});

$("DIV.grid_6 DIV.name").each(function(i, item){
       if (topicName === item){
        alert("do somethign");
        }
     }
```

I have a bunch of DIV.name classes and if the name matches the topicName array, i need to do something;

Comment: Your second `if` statement is painful to look at. Fix your `()` and `{}` please

Comment: And what is `if (topicName === item){}`? If `topciName` is an array you can't just compare values like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="name">jen</div>
<div class="name">bob</div>
<div class="name">sally</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var topicName = ["jen","bob","michelle"];


$("div.name").each(function(){

    var nameFound = $.inArray($(this).text(), topicName);
    if (nameFound === -1){
        alert($(this).text() + " not found in array");
    } else {
        alert($(this).text() + " found in array");
    }

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqGKr/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("DIV.grid_6 DIV.name").each(function(i, item){
    if ( $.inArray( item, topicName ) !== -1 ){
        alert("do somethign");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (topicName === item)
```

do this, if the text to match is the content of the `div`:

```
if ($.inArray($(item).text(), topicName) != -1)
```

or, if it's in an attribute (such as `<div name="foo">`):

```
if ($.inArray($(item).attr('name'), topicName) != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some kind of tricky way like this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = ['foo', 'bar', 'c'];
   //
   // $('.' + a.join(', .')) => $('.foo, .bar, .c')
   //
   $('.' + a.join(', .')).mouseover(function() {
       console.log($(this).attr('class'));
   });
});
```

you can simply select them and do what ever you want. If the name is not exists, there will be no binding. It means no problem at all.